# Meaning of the passage

Tags: meaning

> I said no to him. He had to have me. Once he did, he didn't care.

Is the passage above trying to say that the boy wanted to have the girl, and once he had her, he didn't care for her?

Comment: Your assessment is about as correct as one can achieve without any context.

Answer (score 1):

More context would be great, but the meaning I'm getting is that the girl (assuming we're talking about a heterosexual encounter) initially rebuffed (rejected) the boy's request for sexual intercourse, but he was insistent. The girl finally relented (gave in to the boy's demand). But once the boy had had sex with the girl, he no longer cared for her. In other words, he had only pursued her for the one sexual encounter; she meant nothing to him beyond that.

Comment: It's not entirely clear whether sex is meant just based on the quote. *had her* can also mean as a girlfriend. But I do agree sex is the most likely meaning.